# Proving convexity using the Hessian

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose I have

$f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}_\infty$ which is twice continuously differentiable, on some convex set C, which is open.

How can I prove that $f$ is convex over C, iff the hessian ($\nabla^2 f(x))$ is positive semidefinite $\forall x \in C$ ?

Comment: What is $\Bbb R_\infty$?

Comment: its defined as $\mathbb{R} \cup \{+\infty\}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the hessian is positive semidefinite, and $x_1,x_2\in C$, we want to show that $f(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2) \leq tf(x_1) + (1-t)f(x_2)$. Consider $g(t) = f(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2)$. Write the condition you want to prove of $f$ in terms of $g$. Now, Can you find the second derivative of $g(t)$?

Use the fact that the hessian is positive semidefinite to show that $g''(t)\geq 0$, and now use the Taylor expansion of $g(t)$ around $t=0$ and $t=1$: this gives $$g(0) = g(t) + (0-t)g'(t) + \dfrac{(0-t)^2}{2}g''(\xi) \geq g(t) - tg'(t)$$ and $$g(1) = g(t) + (1-t)g'(t) + \dfrac{(1-t)^2}{2}g''(\xi)\geq g(t) + (1-t)g'(t)$$

Now, this implies $g(t) \leq tg(0) + (1-t)g(1)$, which is what you want.

Comment: Of course, this only goes in one direction. You have proven that if the Hessian is positive semidefinite, then $f$ is convex. It remains to prove the reverse: that if $f$ is convex, then the Hessian is positive semidefinite for all $x\in C$.